# bash: Is there a shortcut to copying a file to multiple places without looping/bash script?

Tags: bash

I tried `cp initial.txt {foo,bar,baz}` but get `baz` is not a directory. And `cp initial.txt foo bar baz` doesn't work either.

Is there a way I can do this without making a shell script and looping and invoking cp multiple times? I'm thinking there has to be a succinct way of doing this.

Comment: Not feasible for my succinct style, more time consuming, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tee`. See this answer on superuser.com:

https://superuser.com/questions/32630/parallel-file-copy-from-single-source-to-multiple-targets

Answer (score 4):

xargs in general is a way to turn loops into single commands, and it will work just fine here, too
e.g.:
echo foo bar baz | xargs -n1 cp initial.txt

However, this does invoke cp multiple times. On the positive side, you can run the cp commands in parallel with the -P option to xargs.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not.  You have to loop.

`cp` does take multiple arguments, but it's only to copy all but the last argument into the last argument, which must then be a directory.

Comment: I'm looking for creative workarounds, not a "no you cannot" strict RTFM type useless answer.

Comment: @meder: is "for i in foo bar baz; do cp initial.txt $i; done" really a problem?  Really?

Comment: `tee foo bar baz < initial.txt` is much more succinct.